# Regx to delete a given pattern in string

Tags: java, regex

In the xml we have  some tags like

`<string1 : string2>`

and many more like this.

i need to write a regular expression to delete all the string end with ":" and i.e. here string1 and ":" also.
and it should be always inside < >

e.g.  Input = `<string1 : string2>`

output = `<string2>`

Comment: do you need to catch closing tags with the same format?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it in php:

```
<?php
 $str = "<string1 : string2>";
 $s = preg_replace('~(</?)[^>:]*:\s*~', "$1", $str);
 var_dump($s);
?>
```

#### EDIT In Java

```
String str = "<ns2:senderId xmlns=\"netapp.com/fsoCanonical\">NetApp</ns2:senderId>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(</?)[^>:]*:\\s*", "$1"));
```

**Output**

```
<senderId xmlns="netapp.com/fsoCanonical">NetApp</senderId>
```

Comment: @satyam: based on comments I have provided you one example in Java above. Hope that meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`<.*?:\s*(.*?)>` should capture only the part you are interested in.  How to do regex replacement can vary from programming language to programming language.

In java you could do

```
string.replaceAll("<.*?:\s*(.*?)>", "<$1>");
```

Comment: so could to tell me how to do it in java

Answer (score 0):

```
<[^>:]*:\s*([^>]*)>
```

Search and replace with `<$1>`.

Comment: Hi jeff thanks a lot its working ,but one more exception.. lets say we have input xml like this                                              <ns1:fso xmlns:ns1="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">
<ns2:senderId xmlns="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">NetApp</ns2:senderId>
<receiverId xmlns="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">Unisys</receiverId>
<messageId xmlns="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">4CF4DC05126A0077E10080000A66C871</messageId>
</ns1:fso>                                                             and we need the output  as below

Comment: <fso xmlns:ns1="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">
<senderId xmlns="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">NetApp</senderId>
<receiverId xmlns="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">Unisys</receiverId>
<messageId xmlns="http://www.netapp.com/fsoCanonical">4CF4DC05126A0077E10080000A66C871</messageId>
</fso>

Answer (score 0):

With an xslt parser you can use

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

[This link is relevant for your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<).*?:\s*(?=.*?>)
```

The look behind ensures the `<` is on the left, then matches your string including the `:` and optional whitespaces. The following look ahead ensures that there is the rest of the tag.

Capture this and replace with an empty string.

You can it see online here [http://regexr.com](http://regexr.com?2tnvk)

[regular-expressions.info/java.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) explains how to apply regexes in java.